# SCALA Option & Map Construct

Tags: scala

Came across this in a discussion on MONADs although a bit hard to follow. But the question is, I can get map and flatmap with Big Data, but the stuff here makes me feel very shaky. firstname => lastname, compounded =>, etc. Not getting it ... Who can explain? It works though.

```
val maybeFirstName = Option("Joe");
val maybeLastName = Option("Black");

val maybeFullName = maybeFirstName.flatMap { firstName =>
  maybeLastName.map { lastName =>
    firstName + " " + lastName
 }
}
```

Comment: What's up with Big Data, I can't quite follow? Why does a code snippet make you "feel shaky". It's a piece of code. It compiles. It does something quite boring, essentially it simply concatenates two strings together. What exactly are you "not getting"?

Comment: It's like nothing I've seen, a concat I guess. But odd that I have never thought of this myself, competent enough.

Comment: @thebluephantom have you tried it when one or both of the values are none?

Comment: Is this a question or a thought?

Comment: you guys really have your cake and eat it too,

Comment: Actually I can't rephrase it as I have got the point on the Option and map, so it woul d make no sense to edit it imho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with many compound operations, it sometimes makes sense to decipher it from the inside out.

```
maybeLastName.map(lastName => /*some op on lastName*/)
```

`map()` opens the `Option` and assigns the value, *if it's there*, to `lastName`. If the `Option` is `None` then there is no `lastName` and no operation on it. If the `Option` is not `None` then operation is performed and the result is re-wrapped into an `Option`.

`flatMap()` does the same thing except that it doesn't re-wrap the result. Instead the op inside is required to return a value *already wrapped*, i.e. an `Option`.

So, to review:

```
maybeFirstName.flatMap { firstName =>  //op on firstName must return Option
  maybeLastName.map { lastName =>      //op on lastName should not return Option
    /* op */
  }
}
```

If either `maybe...Name` is `None` then the final result is `None`.

Comment: Got it, this is the better explanation.

Comment: Both need to be None

Comment: No, `maybeFullName` will be `None` **if** `maybeFirstName` is `None` ,**or** `maybeLastName` is `None`, **or** both are `None`. So `maybeFullName` will be populated (not `None`) only **if** both `maybeFirstName` **and** `maybeLastName` are populated (not `None`).

Comment: I tried and that is what I observed. Interesting, may be I am getting too old...

Comment: The code posted in your question will produce `Some(Joe Black)` or `None`. No intermediate result, `Some(Joe )` or `Some( Black)`, is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Map applies function on maybeLastName and retur Option or `Option(Joe Black)`. So if you use map instead of flatMap, you get `Option(Option(Joe Black))`, because map always return new Option, so to remove inner option you need to use flatMap or combination map and flatten.

Here you can see how works [flatten](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-flatten-list-lists-in-scala-with-flatten-method)

Comment: OK, was not quite the thrust of my question, but indeed true the flatten, I use that myself. But, it just seems rather unusual to me.